# UIWebView screenshot

Tags: ios, uiwebview, screenshot

I'm facing a problem trying to take screenshots form `UIWebViews`. I need to take some screenshots of my `UIWebView` and it works but the screenshot is not correct because they are taken in the event `webViewDidFinishLoad`, but it calls `webViewDidFinishLoad` when the `UIWebView` is not loaded fully, I mean, I take the screenshot in the event `webViewDidFinishLoad` but the `UIWebView` is not correctly and fully loaded so it takes a screenshot and it makes right but the screenshot is not totally correct because its the event is triggered (`webViewDidFinishLoad`) but the `UIWebView` is not totally loaded. Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking screenshot in the event webViewDidFinishLoad you can try to take the screenshot explicitly using UIButton. Let this button be disabled and you can just set this button's enabled property to YES after web view fully loads its content.
On button click to can implement your code to take screenshot.

Edited : Webview's webViewDidFinishLoad method is called when it finishes loading its content. Might be its possible that it may be taking some time to render some images/content on its view.
If possible you can use NSTimer in your webViewDidFinishLoad method to wait for sufficient time(1 min) so that mean while webview can load its content fully.

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(MethodName:)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: NO];

In Selector method you can implement your code of taking screenshot.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Yes, its a solution but it has to be done programatically so I cant use a UIButton to make that. It seems UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad event is triggered when the view is not totally loaded. So I need other solution but thank you very much for your reply

Comment: I have edited my answer above do refer it. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Finally, I forgot to reply, but I used a javascript function to communicate with the UIWebView and take the screenshot in the exact moment I wanted to. Anyway, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

A user was having a issue with their use of a activity indicator that apears until a page has loaded but theirs would come back after the main content had loaded the question is here  [UIWebView not finishing loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288852/uiwebview-not-finishing-loading) and the answer code is used below. After the code I will go into detail about how this could be used for your situation.

(In the code below the web page truly starts loading on `//show UIActivityIndicator` and truly finishes loading the main content (not the extra content you are struggling with) on `//hide UIActivityIndicator`)

```
//Define the NSStrings "lastURL" & "currentURL" in the .h file.
//Define the int "falsepositive" in the .h file. (You could use booleans if you want)
//Define your UIWebView's delegate (either in the xib file or in your code)

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    lastURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", webView.request.mainDocumentURL];
    if (falsepositive != 1) {
        NSLog(@"Loaded");
        //hide UIActivityIndicator
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Extra content junk (i.e. advertisements) that the page loaded with javascript has finished loading");
        //This method may be a good way to prevent ads from loading hehe, but we won't do that
    }
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {
    NSURL *requestURL =[request mainDocumentURL];
    currentURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", requestURL]; //not sure if "%@" should be used for an NSURL but it worked...
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ([currentURL isEqualToString:lastURL]) {
        falsepositive = 1;
        NSLog(@"The page is loading extra content with javascript or something, ignore this");
    } else {
        falsepositive = 0;
        NSLog(@"Loading");
        //show UIActiviyIndicator
    }
}
```

When a page loads in iOS, webviewdidstart and webviewdidfinish are called but not knowing the difference in your main page/html content objective-c calls this again for extra content such as ads or frames. Using this if I were in your situation I would create a BOOL such as pageIsLoading and set it to true in webviewdidstart and then set it to false in webviewdidfinish. After the BOOL is turned off in webviewdidfinish I would end webviewdidfinish by calling a method that will check after a short delay if the BOOL pageIsLoading == YES and if it is, do nothing because more content is loading. If pageIsloading == no then all content must be loaded and now would be a good time to take your snapshot.