# Issue while accessing VPN url in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, vpn

I have configured VPN Network inside the Setting application of my iPad, and I got connect successfully and able to access VPN urls in safari.

Same VPN-URL, I want to access in `UIWebView`, I tried using `loadRequest` and `UIWebViewDelegate`methods but `UIWebView` is not able to open the VPN-URL.

It's continuously showing loading ActivityIndicator (Added by developer on webView), doesn't finish loading and `didFinish` never get a call.

Want your inputs on VPN configuration for Native Apps, if it is different than the normal setting configuration.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288852/uiwebview-not-finishing-loading , probably this is not a vpn problem.

Comment: @dmirkitanov Other url's are opened successfully in webview, only vpn url has issue.

Comment: @MayurBirari will you post the answer / solution ? Facing the same issue here. What different did you do to load the vpn url?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a username to use to log in as. Currently when connecting to your VPN you are defaulting to login (since it is in the webview) as anonymous, and since (I'm guessing) you don't have that user on your VPN it is coming up with an infinitely spinning icon.

What you can do to fix this is to specify a username (and a password if you wish) using this format in the URL: `http://username@hostname.com/`
Which will then prompt you for a password; or do `http://username:password@hostname.com/` if you want to specify the password.

Comment: I tried it, but request fail with Error Message- Can not open this page, possibly not able to connect to the server.